# How to set localized show/hide buttons in NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have NSOutlineView in my App. This function

```
-(BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView*)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item
```

sets some of items in outlineView as a group root(if function returns YES) + adds show/hide buttons at the end of cell to expand/collapse content of this group, but this button written in English. I'm from Belarus, and that is why I want show/hide words written in my language. Finder writes in my language, that is why i think, what there is some option to set it localized style for it.
How I can do this?

**SOLVED:**
Mac OS does this itself at the time of choosing localization of .nib file what contains `NSOutineView`

Answer (score 0):

The official way to retrieve the localized show/hide button (as well as the disclosure button) is now [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Outline_View_Button_Keys) in the NSOutlineView Class Reference.

```
let showHideButton = outlineView.makeViewWithIdentifier(NSOutlineViewShowHideButtonKey, owner: outlineView.delegate()) as? NSButton
```

It's important to note the `state` property of the button controls the Hide/Show title, which by default is not synced to the state of the NSOutlineView:

- `NSOnState` = "Hide"
- `NSOffState` = "Show"

> `NSOutlineViewDisclosureButtonKey`
>   **The normal triangle disclosure button.**
>
> `NSOutlineViewShowHideButtonKey`
>   **The Show/Hide button.**
>
> The outline view creates these buttons by calling its inherited
>   `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` method, passing in the key as the
>   identifier and the delegate as the owner.
>
> These keys are backwards compatible to OS X v10.7, however, the
>   symbol is not exported prior to v10.9 and the string value
>   (@"NSOutlineViewDisclosureButtonKey") must be used.